# Character error with simple lambda formula

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying some stuff with the heapq package now. I have this dataset:

```
portfolio = [

{'shares':100,'price':50},
{'shares':200,'price':53},
]
```

I try to get the cheapest share now with the following formula:

```
Cheap = heapq.nsmallest(1, portfolio, key = lambda s:  s[‘price’])
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unknown character
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: Did you copy paste the `‘price’`? Try retyping the '.

Comment: To clarify, your "quotes" are incorrect around price, it seems. Change the quotes to `'` or `"`.

Answer (score -1):

If you've cut and pasted your actual script

```
Cheap = heapq.nsmallest(1, portfolio, key = lambda s:  s[‘price’])
```

then you are using "curly quotes" (`‘price’`) instead of the required normal quotes (`'price'`).

Comment: It probably would have been better to help vote up the duplicate instead.

Comment: yep, didn't think to look, although note that the error message is subtly different...